# Mixing of two arrays of variable size in Minizinc

Tags: arrays, minizinc

I have two arrays a and b of variable sizes.

I want to write a function that accepts these two arrays and will return me a new array c (length(c) is length(a) + length(b)) with these characteristics:-

- The variables must be in the same order as they appear in original arrays, for example, a = [x,y,z,a,b] and b = [p,q,r], then c must be like this
  c = [x,p,q,y,z,r,a,b] (basically interleaving of two arrays maintaning the order) or it can be like this c = [p,x,q,r,y,z,a,b]

  ```
  function array[int] of var int : mixed(array[int] of var int: a, 
  array[int] of var int: b) = 
  let { array [1 .. length(a++b)] of var int : c = %some magic here
  } in c
  ;
  ```

  I tried several array comprehensions but failed.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your problem correctly, then you are looking for a function that returns an array that can contain all possible interleavings of the the two given arrays.

This problem is more complicated as it seems, since the resulting array can not be compromised of the same variables as the arguments, but must be variables in their own right.

I'm afraid I can't see a way of doing this within a comprehension, but using a few globals. A working function can be comprised:

```
include "globals.mzn";

function array[int] of var int: interleave(array[int] of var int: a, array[int] of var int: b) = let {
        array[index_set(a)] of var 1..length(a ++ b): map_a;
        array[index_set(b)] of var 1..length(a ++ b): map_b;
        array[1..length(a ++ b)] of var dom_bounds_array(a ++ b): c;
        constraint all_different(map_a ++ map_b);
        constraint forall(i in index_set(a)) (c[map_a[i]] = a[i]);
        constraint increasing(map_a);
        constraint forall(i in index_set(b)) (c[map_b[i]] = b[i]);
        constraint increasing(map_b);
    } in c;
```

---

**Misunderstood solution:** 1 by 1 element picking:

The solution to your problem is to combine multiple comprehensions:

- A comprehension for the interleaved arrays where elements are chosen from each array one at a time.
- Comprehensions to add the remainder of the elements if one array is longer than the other.

The resulting function would be:

```
function array[int] of var int: interleave(array[int] of var int: a, array[int] of var int: b) = let {
        array[int] of int: ai = [ i | i in index_set(a)];
        array[int] of int: bi = [ i | i in index_set(b)];
        int: share = min(length(a), length(b));
    } in [ if x = 1 then a[ai[i]] else b[bi[i]] endif | i in 1..share, x in 1..2]
        ++ [ a[ai[i]] | i in share+1..length(a) ]
        ++ [ b[bi[i]] | i in share+1..length(b) ];
```

It is also important to note that in MiniZinc the index set does not need to be continuous. Therefore we use an comprehension to get all elements from the index set as well. This is mainly to make this function useble on any kind of MiniZinc array.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But this is straightforward and does not cover any randomness. Actually it is picking values one-by-one from arrays. 
array c can be in any random order, example, [x,y,z,p,q,r,a,b], etc.
These cannot be covered with this solution.

Comment: @RajatGupta I'm sorry, I was a bit too quick to answer. I'll edit my answer in when in a few hours